# What CellID database does Apple query in iOS CoreLocation API?

Tags: ios, core-location, cellid

I am really curious to know what CellID database Apple uses inorder to enable CellID based Location in CoreLication API of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I think it relates to the question: http://techcrunch.com/2010/07/29/apple-location/

For devices running iPhone OS versions 1.1.3 to 3.1, Apple relied on (and still relies on) databases maintained by Google and Skyhook Wireless (“Skyhook”) to provide location-based services. Beginning with the iPhone OS version 3.2 released in April 2010, Apple relies on its own databases to provide location-based services and for diagnostic purposes.